# How to specify file:// path to svn on Windows (redmine)?

Tags: windows, svn, file, redmine

I use Redmine and I'm trying to specify a SVN repository for my project. 
I have SVN in Z:\svn and let's assume my project's name is "myproject".
In Eclipse it works if I enter file:///svn/myproject as repository path. 
It doesn't work in Redmine though.
I tried slashes, backslashes, with or without "Z:".

Does "file" protocol specification say anything about drive letters? Or is it Redmine-related shortcoming? How to make it work?

All the programs (Eclipse, Redmine) are on Z: drive.

Comment: The correct answer usually is `file:///z:/svn/myproject`, but I assume you already tried that.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Does Eclipse support File Protocol "file:///svn/myproject"(verify)!
I.e GO serve doesn't 
Try to use svn+ssh or https